# ROS for ubuntu precise 12.04

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

There is any date for the launch of a ros realease for ubuntu 12.04? There is any beta repository available?

Many thanks,
Filipe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32867/ros-for-ubuntu-precise-12.04/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-04-27

Post score: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The build farm is still being set up for releasing Ubuntu Precise binary packages. I expect it will be ready soon, but don't know when. Maybe one of the people working on it can provide an estimate.

You can try [building Fuerte from source](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source) right now, I suppose. There may be problems with some dependencies missing from Precise.

UPDATE: you can view the progress of Debian packages for Precise on the [Fuerte debbuild status page](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html).

UPDATE (2012-05-03): most Fuerte Precise packages look to be available now, including `ros-fuerte-perception-pcl`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on 2012-04-30**:
I have tried but I am getting troubles from python 2.7. In the roscore I get auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'>. Anyone had this problem?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-30**:
You will need to install the new catkin build tools and learn how to use them. The ROS core is no longer built with rosmake.

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2012-04-30**:
Thanks Jack.  I'll try this again.  I tried last Thursday, but the install failed and rather than delve deep into why, I simply reverted everything.  I'll post here if there are still issues.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-30**:
Good idea, Patrick. I would not be very surprised if we find some holes in the documentation. If there are, let's fix them.

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2012-04-30**:
Not just documentation holes, rosdep install problems on Precise.  Just doesn't work properly (see answer below).

**Comment by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on 2012-04-30**:
Jack O'Quin do you know if there is any beta document,  available, to build ros fuerte with catkin? this http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian works in section 1.3.1 (Install core libraries), with problems in roscore (like i told before). If i try 1.3.2 i lost roscore, roscd...

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2012-05-03**:
@Filipe Santos: I get that error too; just filed a ticket about it: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3950.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no prebuilt install for Precise as of now.  And the source install linked above doesn't work for Precise.  Here's where I got into problems last Friday (and I am there again).  When following the source install for oneiric on precise I can get pretty far (though there are missing packages and missing dependencies in the rosdep yaml files that must be hand edited).  Then it starts trying to install things like ros-fuert-pcl that has a hard dependency on mysqlclient16, but precise only has mysqlclient18.  So, then you have to start downloading .deb files and forcing them to install and ignore dependency issues.  This is not ideal, and I refuse to start compromising the integrity of my OS packaging system by doing this shoehorning (not to mention that it's terribly difficult to know what ros-fuerte-* packages that rosdep wants, so I'd have to download the entire fuerte distribution and hand install all these "Layer 2" tools that rosdep install tries to install via apt-get ros-fuerte-xx).

So, as of now, I'm going to say that Fuerte is NOT installable (by any normal means) on Precise.  I really wish someone would have started looking at this stuff when the Precise Beta was released a month ago, but oh well.  In the meantime, none of my new machines can be used for ROS programming.

---

Originally posted by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) with karma: 276 on 2012-04-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2012-04-30**:
To even get this far, there are things that need to be done: 1) apt-get install python-empy and python-nose, 2) after rosdep init, find python-qt-bindings in the local rosdep cache, and add a line for precise, 3) fix precise dependency for yaml-cpp in rosdep cache to look like oneiric.

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2012-04-30**:
Got further than above by adding oneiric sources to my apt sources list, but then it gets into a loop where ros-fuerte-pcl installs libjpeg68-dev then ros-fuerte-opencv2 require libjpeg62-dev.  Manually install 62 which remove 68, then re-running rosdep simply reinstall 68 in order to reinstall pcl.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-30**:
Thanks for the details, Patrick. Negative results are helpful, too. I suppose those bringing up the Precise build machines will solve these issues as soon as they can.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source
UPDATE: The section 1.5.1 and 1.5.2 it works perfectly! After compiling the tools... they are working, rviz, turtlesim all fine! (After install some deb packages, like: eigen, libxml, curl, nvidea_tolkit...)

OBSERVATION: Python 2.7.3 from ubuntu 12.04 have some problem and I: see Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'>. But all fine!

---

Originally posted by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) with karma: 346 on 2012-04-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-30**:
Just curious (and I'm not sure if there are actually any significant differences) but is there any reason you aren't using the Ubuntu source install docs (since you are on Ubuntu)? http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

**Comment by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on 2012-04-30**:
Eric, I think that they are the same! The only change that i made was to put precise instead of oneiric in the deb rep: sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list.. The problem, is now solved, the problem was my mistake!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-01**:
Good progress, Filipe! I don't know of any additional documentation. The Debian and Ubuntu souce build instructions are similar, but the Debian version has some additional comments.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-01**:
Asking new questions in an "answer" does not really work for this forum. Please edit your original question, or post a new one.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-01**:
There is a new procedure for submitting rosdep rules updates: http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2012-05-02**:
Following http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source does not simply "work perfectly".   I tried (yet again) and get stuck in the same place as noted in my answer.

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2012-05-02**:
Also there is no Section 1.3.1/1.3.2, so I'm unsure exactly what you are doing to make this work.  1.5.1 and 1.5.2 work, but Section 1.7 does not, as pcl and opencv depend on conflicting packages in Precise.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-02**:
I think he is still referring to the Debian instructions: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian#fuerte.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-rosinstall.rosinstall

**Comment by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on 2012-05-02**:
pbeeson In section 1.2 I used "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main". In 1.7, i had troubles with python-qt-bindings. But I had compile, rviz,amcl, gazebo and my stuff and all works fine! (offcourse that I have installed some deb manually, because i don't understand well rosdep!)

**Comment by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on 2012-05-02**:
I haven't compiled pcl... but my stuff uses opencv, and works fine (I have installed opencv from synaptic)... Probably there is some wrong repository, no?

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2012-05-02**:
NOTE: If you only use precise in 1.2, you have to follow the debian instructions for building your own swig-wx.  Also, 1.7 became such a hassle (rosinstall tries to install ros-fuerte-opencv, etc that don't yet exist for precise) that I gave up.  Could not rosmake things I need (e.g. PCL) by hand.